# No Endpoint listening error?

Tags: .net, wcf

I have been getting this error intermittantly since I launched the site (once every couple weeks). However now they have been more frequent, several each day. Strangely enough these recent ones all seem to be from various Mozilla broswers. I don't see how that would have anything to do with the issue though.

I have already checked the logs on the web server (GoDaddy) and WCF Server (local). I also checked the firewall on the WCF server. I am just at a loss of what to check next, any ideas?

Comment: Betcha the web server is recycling when it goes down.

Comment: How would I be able to tell if that is the case? I see nothing in the logs at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled WCF tracing on the client? If not, you could try it. It might reveal some extra information. You can do it like this:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\path\to\logfile.svclog"/>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

This will log extensively, so make sure that you have diskquota for it. You need to use the service trace viewer program to view the generated log file. It comes with the windows sdk.

Comment: I just added the logging, now I just have to wait for another error. I will let you know what I find out. Thanks!

Comment: @user372234 you can add it to the service's web.config too and see if that reveals something.

Comment: Finally some errors happened now that I turned the logging on. I have looked at the log and I don't see anything at all going on at the times the errors happened, I am not sure what to think. 

Any ideas?

Comment: @user372234. Do you notice any activity in the logfile at all half an hour prior to the error? If not then it's probably due to IIS going to sleep because of inactivity. You can increase the idle time in IIS if this is the case.

Comment: I do see activity right before and right after the errors. I listens happening about 5 minutes before and a minute after.

Comment: @user372234, and you don't see a red entry in the log saying "throwing an exception" when viewing the logfile in service trace viewer?

Comment: No I don't see an error. I think it might be a server issue in that the server isn't being reached, but of course my ISP doesn't want to believe that so I am trying everything to prove it to them.


The exception I am getting is on the website not the WCF, should I add the logging to the website too?

Comment: @user372234. **Yes**, I thought you had already done that. Logging on both ends always gives most information.